Azure Notification Hub device not recognized
I'm working with the Azure Notification Hub and a C# application. If I request all registered devices through Hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);, I see a number of devices.
Two of these devices, I'm focussing on. They have both the same tags. They are both Apple registrations.
However, if I send a notification to one of the tags both devices have, only one device get's the notification.
If I do this through the azure "Test send", also only one device is shown. It look likes it doesn't recognize it's own registration anymore. But it still shows up through the GetAllRegistrations call.
Any clue what could be the issue here?
[Edit]
Also with the GetRegistrationsByTagAsync call, I get my device back from the Hub. When I create/send a notification, and check the detailed result, I only see one device, not the other.
If I retrieve all registrations on a unique tag (for the device I'm missing the notifications for), it returns this specific device. When sending a notification to it, results in an success response without devices (so basically, nothing send)

It was caused by debugging on the live notification hub. There is a mismatch in profiles if you do this
